# freemarker select tag

Tags: forms, struts2, freemarker

Is there a way to check freemarker <#if> condition inside the <@s.select tag>?

for example i need sometething like

```
<@s.select id="myId" 
        name="travellerModif[2].type"
        value="${modifiedTraveller.type}"
        list="personTypeOpt" listKey="code" listValue="label"
       <#if modifiedTraveller.modifType == "SUPPRESS">cssClass="hidden"</#if>/>
```

But this is gicing me error:

```
 Encountered: &quot;#&quot; (35), after : &quot;&quot; in
```

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I'd create the class value outside of the tag, and make it much easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the default of `cssClass` is `""` (or whatever known value), you could utilize boolean-formatting:

```
<@s.select
        ...
        cssClass=(modifiedTraveller.modifType == "SUPPRESS")?string("hidden", "") />
```

Otherwise you have to use two @s.select calls and put them into an #if/#else.